# How to correctly make use of multithreading to run my program faster?

Tags: multithreading, python-sounddevice

How can I correctly make my code run faster? Following is my attempt at making use of multithreading. However, I do not understand where to join the threads. I want the results to be printed serially, but computed parallely.

```
import queue
import datetime
from time import sleep
import sounddevice as sd
import threading

def transcribe(audio):
    sleep(10)
    print("Hello World")

class RealtimeTranscriber():
    NUM_BLOCK = 20
    N_FRAMES = 3000
    SAMPLE_RATE = 16000
    def __init__(self):
        
        def on_parse_block(indata, frame_count, time, status):
            del frame_count, time, status
            self.q.put((datetime.datetime.now(), indata.ravel()))
        
        def on_parse_sequence():
            pass
        
        self.q = queue.Queue()
        
        self.stream = sd.InputStream(
            device=0,
            channels=1,
            samplerate=self.SAMPLE_RATE,
            blocksize=self.N_FRAMES * self.NUM_BLOCK,
            dtype="float32",
            callback=on_parse_block,
            finished_callback=on_parse_sequence
            )
        
        with self.stream:
            while True:
                try:
                    try:
                        timestamp, audio = self.q.get()
                        t = threading.Thread(target=self.transcribe, args=(audio,))
                        t.start()
                    except queue.Empty:
                        pass
                except KeyboardInterrupt:
                    break
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    transcriber = RealtimeTranscriber()
```